# Watch a directory and handle complete new files as soon as possible

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, node.js, watch

I have a directory where some other programs write XML files that I have to process when they're complete.

Until now I avoided the handling of incompletely written files by asking the writing programs to first use a temporary name and only at end rename the files in `".xml"`. My code looks like this :

```
var fs  = require("fs");
var handleFiles = function(){
    fs.readdirSync(args.in).forEach(function(filename) {
        if (filename.slice(-4)!=='.xml') return;
        // handle XML file here
    });
}
fs.watch(args.in, handleFiles);
```

But some new programs I have to support are unable to write with a temporary name.

How can I ensure I handle the files when they're completely written in an efficient, reliable, cross-browser (windows & linux) and not timeout-based (i.e. not testing a rename every 10 ms until it works) way ?

Writing operations are one-shot, so I guess what I want (for linux and more importantly for windows) is to be notified when there are new files not being write-locked.

Comment: Linux does not write-lock files implicitly. If you want locking to happen, use `flock` or `lockf` explicitly. In particular, two processes could write the same file simultaneously (even if that is not preferable).

Answer (score 1):

On linux you could use the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) facilities. See [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

Maybe using [incrontab](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) could be worthwhile.

Comment: Well, that's already what I do since I use `fs.watch`, but my problem is 1) cross-browser 2) to be notified when a file isn't written any more.

Comment: You should define what a file being not written any more means to you. What about files open in append mode? Eg someone do `someprog > out.xml` and 5 minutes (or 30 seconds) later `someotherprog >> out.xml` ? In that case, when is `out.xml` not written any more??

Comment: Such a file would be being written. I guess a file is being written when it's write locked.

Answer (score 0):

One technique for dealing with this is to use a zero-byte "signal file" which is written after the main file is done. For example

```
mybigfile.txt
mybigfile.txt.done
```

The ".done" file is 0 bytes long and is created by a "touch" or similar process when it has finished writing the data file. You scan for the .done file and don't do anything if it is missing. Unfortunately you imply that you can't control the writing processes, so this might not be a solution you can use.

Comment: The problem is to deal with writing programs that are too simple to handle this.